# Android Grid View Images : Show Text

Tags: android

I have prepared a grid view in a fragment which shows images and when you click on them it shows the image in another Activity. I want the name of the image to be shown below it for that i took a textview but it shows position. How to show the name of the photo choosen from grid view on that textview. Below is the code fragments.

full_image_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="500dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/image_title"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FullImageFragment

```
package com.androidbelieve.HIT_APP;

import android.app.Activity;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 2/13/2016.
 */
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FullImageFragment extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image_layout);

        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_title);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));
    }

}
```

GalleryFragment

```
package com.androidbelieve.HIT_APP;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * Created by Ratan on 7/29/2015.
 */
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery_grid, container,
                false);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(view.getContext()));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),FullImageFragment.class);
                i.putExtra("id",position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Please Help Me Out!!!

Comment: Can you please post ImageAdapter code snippet ?

Comment: You have to make a custom Class to store image id and name, make array of those objects and use in ImageAdapter.

Comment: can u please show how, I dont know much about it

Answer (score 1):

ImageAdapter

```
package com.androidbelieve.HIT_APP;

/**
 * Created by Akash on 2/13/2016.
 */
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;


    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.akash, R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash , R.drawable.akash,

    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),FullImageFragment.class);
            i.putExtra("id",position);
            i.putExtra("image_name",arrayImageName[position]); // get your selected image name and pass it
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

In your image display class,

```
    String name = i.getExtras().getString("image_name");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_title);
    textView.setText(name);
```

Comment: where to define that arrayImageName

Comment: Define same way where you have set your image resources array.

Comment: i have not set any image resources array

Comment: Images you are displaying is from server or gallery images or from drawable? How did u get images?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
// Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.akash, R.drawable.akash,
            R.drawable.akash , R.drawable.akash,

    };

 public String[] mThumbNames = {
           "akash 0", "akash 1","akash 2", "akash 3",

    };
```

In Next Activity:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_title);
textView.setText(imageAdapter.mThumbNames[position])
```

**Edit 1:**

```
private class CustomClass{
        public int drawable;
        public String title;
        public String information;
    }
   ArrayList<CustomClass> listCustom = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.akash, R.drawable.akash,
                R.drawable.akash , R.drawable.akash,

        };

        String[] mThumbNames = {
                "akash 0", "akash 1","akash 2", "akash 3",

        };

        String[] mThumbInfos = {
                "akash 0 Info", "akash 1 Info","akash 2 Info", "akash 3 Info",

        };

        for (int i = 0; i < mThumbIds.length; i++) {
            CustomClass customClass = new CustomClass();
            customClass.drawable = mThumbIds[i];
            customClass.title = mThumbNames[i];
            customClass.information = mThumbInfos[i];

            listCustom.add(customClass);
        }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what if i put another image whose file name is xyz then how will it show xyz

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh, you should put name of image.

Comment: Ok like akash,xyz,abc n in that order i should place the images

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh, exactly

Comment: Right. what if suppose I put a picture of some say xyz animal and want to write information about it say 2 lines then I can't put so much text there. so how to do that

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh, you can put also description, what issue you are getting for information

Comment: is there any other way around like using array list or something. What u said is correct but the code looks little bit shabby

Comment: @AkashdeepSingh, yes arraylist is better option for data binding, you can use ArrayList<CustomClass>

Comment: yeah can u please tell me how to do it by seeing the code above

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you want something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Hiren Patel has already answered that. I am just putting it in steps.

1) create 'CustomClass' which will act as POJO class to structure your image name, resource reference.
2) Create an adapter with extends ArrayAdapter and take 'CustomClass' as argument
3) In your activity, create a list of that class and load the data (Image name, resource id etc)
4)Initialize your adapter with above list (can be array as well)
5) access that values on getView method of adapter